# Cannot get ASP.NET Web API routing to work at all

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, controller, rest

I am trying to refactor an old setup, the end goal will be that I will have a functional REST API. I am getting rid of an old NuGet service and I sort of have to rebuild everything now. I am trying to set it up using ASP.NET Web API. This will include 60+ routes (like "www.website.com/cars/{id}/engine" "www.website.com/inventory/{id}" etc..)

I have tried attribute routing and conventional routing, and nothing seems to work. I get 404's no matter what I seem to try. I am probably just not doing either of them correctly.

Here is how I am setting up configuration (I am using a self hosting package btw but this is the main configuration point):

```
public class SomeHostClass
{

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
 { 
  HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

  //If I am trying attribute based routing, uncomment this
  //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

  Register(config.Routes);

  // I think I need this at all times?
  app.UseWebApi(config);
 }

public void Register(HttpRouteCollection routes)
 {
    // One of many other routes.MapHttpRoute() calls
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Cars",
    routeTemplate: "cars/{id}/engine",
    defaults: new
    {
      controller = "CarController",
      action = "Get"
    },
    constraints: null);
 }

}
```

Then here is my Car Controller:

```
public class CarController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get([FromUri] CarDTO carObject)
    {
        // Some code calling a private worker method
        return WorkerMethod();
    }

    private object WorkerMethod()
    {
        // Worker method do stuff, return
    }
}
```

This Get() method is never called and a 404 is returned.

**Another note**: I have tried using reflection to register all the routes, which slims down the code. I'll debug it and it looks like all the routes have been configured correctly within the HttpConfiguration.routes but I will get 404's still. Even without reflection doing it the way shown above- if I debug and look at the values they all seem correct, but don't work.

**Another Note**: I should also mention that this is the error I usually get along with the 404.

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8000/cars/1/engine'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'CarController'."}
```

How do I get these routes recognized and stop returning 404's and start returning my data?

If this is a bad way of going about this- what's the best way?

Comment: Are you allowed to update the routes or is it required to use the same routes?

Comment: You have only one route configured? Is the `default` route configuration added first or last? What's the API URL you are trying to call?

Comment: I recall a thing with similar problems to yours where we were upgrading old code, and that turned out to be we'd imported the wrong namespace for the HttpGet etc attributes - they're present in two NS and need to be matched for the type of controller used. Can't quite remember the exact details, but it was something like "if it's an API controller it needs routing attributes from X namespace, if it's an MVC controller it needs routing attributes from Y namespace" think one of the namespaces mentioned mvc and the other didn't.. I'll see if I can find some more detail

Comment: You could also look at making a new project of the type of service you want to make and check that the weather forecast controller (or whatever the sample is) does work as you expect, then copy the namespaces, and base class part of the file and paste into what you're upgrading/ or compare them to see if anything is different

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not sure what you will expect to happen with your setup as it is- you've got a route that has an {id}, and you've got a method that says an entire dto is encoded in the uri- are you expecting some background magic to turn eg an ID Integer into a DTO? If a complex object is an api controller method parameter I would expect that it is more often FromBody and is a block of Json as the request payload, not encoded in the uri. Perhaps start from a working sample and proceed with modifying it til it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments @ShawnOrr To answer your questions: I am not really able to do much updating as far as the pre existing routes go. Because there are so many.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have more than one route configured, but I am only showing one here for an example

Comment: @CaiusJard I think all the namespaces are good, except there is an unloaded project within my solution that has some even older api code, maybe its somehow getting confused even though the old project is unloaded? I am expecting a little bit of magic to happen with the DTO to be honest. Our old NuGet package we were using was set up to take in a RequestDTO and it was mappable. I thought FromBody or FromUri was able to handle that. I thought I was able to get that working once but maybe not

Comment: I'd say just drop to a simple int id for now (`public object Get(int id)`),and see if it works.. Or start over with a new working project from template; if you'd done that 15h ago (you probably had this problem for much longer before that "moment where you asked the question" too) I'm sure you'd be further on by now :D

Comment: @CaiusJard So I tried changing it to just "public object Get(int id)" and still nothing. I also tried starting from scratch in a new project and solution and still no dice, sadly. Thanks again though for the suggestions!

Comment: What url are you trying to use? If you have changed the method to `public object Get(int id)`, then a url like this should get there: `https://localhost:[yourPortNumber]/api/Car/15`.

Comment: @ShawnOrr the URL I would be using would be ```http://localhost:8000/cars/1/engine``` in this case

Comment: You started a brand new project and it didn't work? As in, you make a new net core rest api, and it loads with a fake Weather service and not even that worked?

Comment: @CaiusJard Sorry, I didn't make the weather app. I started a new project and moved my current code over to it to isolate it (and cut it down to only one route etc) to try to figure out what was wrong with it

Comment: I suggest you use the weather app, get it calling and working, then move the code (contents of the method, not the method signature/routing) and make sure it still works, then make routing changes. Tbh I've always preferred putting the entire route in an attribute rather than splitting routing over controller attribute and method attribute because when /some/page/x has a problem and he codebase is huge, ctrl-f can get straight to the code just by searching the route